# Lasers: why when a photon kicks a excited electron, the two released photons have the same polarization?

Tags: photons, laser, polarization

When a photon kicks a excited electron, why do the two released photons have the same polarization?

I was playing with some lasers and am trying to understand the principles at play. I just read about what polarization is in light waves, and I wonder: considering the excited electron is present at the edge of a particle, why does the released photon share direction and phase?

Honestly, I would have thought the released electron would be released in an angle or something. similar to what happens when two billard balls collide.

Can you elaborate a little bit about why this happens, please?

Comment: You'll have to be a bit more specific what sort of laser you're talking about because not all lasers emit polarized light, cf. e.g. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/183216/50583, so the explanation of the mechanism will depend on the actual kind of laser.

Comment: ohhh thanks, this is a CO2 laser, the one you use to cut things, I was watching this video about the topic also: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_JOchLyNO_w